# What set is this from? (spiky transparent blue with axle hole in the center)

Tags: part-identification, set-identification

Does anyone know what this piece is? I have asked people around if they know what piece it is. They didn't know it. It has an axle hole in the center.

All help appreciated
[image: spiky transparent blue with axle hole in the center]
[image: spiky transparent blue with axle hole in the center]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Looks like part [98578 Hero Factory Weapon: Spiked Ball, Half](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=98578&idColor=14) in transparent dark blue (found by a bricklink search for pieces named "half" in trans-blue).

[It appears in two sets](https://www.bricklink.com/catalogItemIn.asp?P=98578&colorID=14&in=A): [70202-1 "Chi Gorzan"](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?S=70202-1) from Legends of Chima, and [45560-1 "EV3 expansion set"](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?S=45560-1).

Comment: Given that the posters previous question was about programming, I'd think that the EV3 expansion set is more likely. Also regarding ownership, I've bought half a dozen of this set. At the time, there were some online stores around here that offered them significantly cheaper than RRP and the boxes were ideal part donor sets for anyone interested in technic/mindstorms....

Comment: That's a good point. I'll rephrase.